# Pgfplots: 3D plot with shader=interp and opacity

Tags: pgfplots, transparency

I have a rather simple question : is there a way to use shader=interp with an opacity factor in a surf mesh ? Here is an example that does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\h{1.5}
\def\mult{4}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,view={20}{50},zmin=-4,zmax=4,
      variable=\s,variable y=\t,domain=0:1,hide axis,
      colormap={custom}{color(0)=(cyan) color(1)=(orange)}]

\def\triangleParamX{\s}
\def\triangleParamY{(1-\s)*\t}

\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0,0,-\h) (0,0,\h)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0,0.5,-\h) (0,0.5,\h)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0,1,-\h) (0,1,\h)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0.5,0.5,-\h) (0.5,0.5,\h)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(1,0,-\h) (1,0,\h)};
\addplot3[opacity=0.5,surf,shader=interp] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,\mult*1-\mult*3*x-\mult*3*y+\mult*4*x*y+\mult*2*x*x+\mult*2*y*y);
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,0,0) (0,0,0)};
\addplot3[black,mark=none] coordinates {(0.5,0,-\h) (0.5,0,\h)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following result:

[image: shader=interp, opacity does not work]

However, if you just replace `shader=interp` with `shader=flat` in the latter example, you get the following:

[image: shader=flat, opacity works]

Here, opacity works, but I do not want the lines on the surface. Is there a trick to make this work ?

Cheers

Comment: It seems you are using old version of `pgfplots`. With v1.11 it works for me.

Comment: I was indeed using an out-of-date version. However, after updating all packages (I use TexLive and TexShop), the result is still the same. I checked, and the pgfplots version I have now is the v1.11. Do you see any other possibility ?

Comment: I have checked the example with lots of different versions of `pgfplots` (1.3, 1.5, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11) and all worked fine. Are sure this is not simply a viewer deficiancy? Some viewers still have bugs, especially regarding shadings.

Comment: @Scrimbibete did you check in other viewers? Which viewer were you using when you noticed this problem?

Comment: Sorry for not answering back, things got pretty busy and I had to focus on other stuff for a while... well you know what it is. I checked on other viewers, without better results, the result I obtain is still opaque. I tried updating texlive, then all packages, then texshop, but the result won't change. I tried with Preview (MacOs) and Adobe. I don't have much time at the moment to make other tests, but I should be able to come back to the problem a bit later. If you have additional ideas, I am still interested ! Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not really an answer, but more kind of an evolution of the situation. I recently updated Adobe Reader, and now the `shader=interp` works with `opacity` (see picture). It is however still not okay in other viewers.

Thanks for everyone's time anyway ! :)

[image]